# Is there alternative to ttl "time to live" for iOS in firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending the notifications using admin sdk.

This is my payload. I was able to set ttl (Time to Live) for Android but I am not sure how I can make it for iOS.

Basically if notification fails to send, then I dont want to resend it at all.

```
         const payload = {
             notification: {
                title: 'New Appointments!',
                body: '',
              },
             data: {},
             android: {
               ttl: 1000, 
             },
             apns: {
               payload: {
                 aps: {
                   badge: 1,
                  "sound":"default"
                 },
               },
             },
            };
admin.messaging().send(payload).then((response) => {})
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [`apns-expiration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html):

> A UNIX epoch date expressed in seconds (UTC). This header identifies the date when the notification is no longer valid and can be discarded.
>
> If this value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed if it is unable to deliver the notification the first time. If the value is 0, APNs treats the notification as if it expires immediately and does not store the notification or attempt to redeliver it.

An example of this is seen in the [FCM docs for ttl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl):

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    },
    "apns":{
      "headers":{
        "apns-expiration":"1604750400"
      }
    },
    "android":{
      "ttl":"4500s"
    },
    "webpush":{
      "headers":{
        "TTL":"4500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between ttl and apns-expiration?

Comment: is 1604750400 seconds or milliseconds and why it's format different than ttl : 4500s?

Comment: is 1604750400  equal to 4500s?

Comment: @HamzaMuazzam It's Unix Time. Specific for APNS.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem I had was wrong format because I was reading the wrong documentation.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#ApnsConfig.

```
 "apns":{
      headers:{
        "apns-expiration":"1604750400"
      }
    }
```